# Summation and Product sum of series

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, summation

what is the answer of

$$\sum_{m=1}^B\Pi_{n=1}^A \frac{m+n}{mn}=?$$

What I tried

$$\sum_{m=1}^B\Pi_{n=1}^A (\frac{1}{m} +\frac{1}{n})$$

$$\sum_{m=1}^B[(\frac{1}{m} +\frac{1}{1})(\frac{1}{m} +\frac{1}{2})...(\frac{1}{m} +\frac{1}{A})]$$

$$=[((\frac{1}{1} +\frac{1}{1})(\frac{1}{1} +\frac{1}{2})...(\frac{1}{1} +\frac{1}{A}))+((\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{1})(\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2})...(\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{A}))+...+((\frac{1}{B} +\frac{1}{1})(\frac{1}{B} +\frac{1}{2})...(\frac{1}{B} +\frac{1}{A}))]$$

I get this answer. Can there be any further simplification or solution?

Comment: Why would $\sum_{m=1}^B\prod_{n=1}^A\left(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\right) = \prod_{n=1}^A\sum_{m=1}^B\left(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\right)$? A simple check with $A=B=2$ shows that this is not true.

Comment: as @kccu said for $ A=B=2 $ you will get $4.5$ for the first one and $8.75$ for the second one. you made a mistake.

Comment: @Babydesta as you mention, I just correct the order. now can it be further simplified?